# Snowball microphone no longer shared between applications

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, pulseaudio, skype, audacity

I recently bought a Snowball USB microphone for a podcast. Previously, I would record my track using audacity, and simultaneously use the microphone for Skype.

I tried to do this yesterday and was unable to do so. If I record with the microphone selected in Audacity, I can record, but then the mic picks up no sound in Skype, and if I use the mic in Skype, Audacity doesn't even list the microphone as an available device for recording.

How can I use my microphone for both Skype and Audacity (or in general, share the mic between applications)?